# How to read a file from /begin/ to /end/, if both may be on the same line

Tags: sed, grep, scripting

I want to read the prototype of a C function through the source code of a big project.

I know the function name, and its return type, and that its prototype will be defined in a `*.h` file.

I'd use [`grep(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), but I want to be able to read multi-line prototypes, so it's discarded.

So what I usually do is:

- project: `glibc`
- return type: `int`
- function name: `cacheflush`

```
syscall='cacheflush';
find glibc/ -name '*.h' \
|xargs sed -n "/^[a-z ]*int ${syscall}[ ]*(/,/^$/p";
```

But that prints some unwanted lines after the ones I want:

```
$ find glibc/ -name '*.h' \
  |xargs sed -n "/^[a-z ]*int ${syscall}[ ]*(/,/^$/p";
extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, int __nbytes, int __op) __THROW;
#endif

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes,
               const int __op) __THROW;
#endif

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
#endif
extern int _flush_cache (char *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
#endif
extern int _flush_cache (char *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
```

I'd like to be able to replace the end pattern `/^$/`-> `/;/`, but then it'll only work when the function prototype spans across multiple lines.  Is it possible to tell [`sed(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) that the end pattern might be on the same line as the begin pattern, so that the output would be the following?:

```
$ find glibc/ -name '*.h' | xargs sed magic;
extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, int __nbytes, int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes,
               const int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pcregrep`'s multi-line mode:

```
$ pcregrep --include='\.h$' -rM '(?s)^\s*(\w+\s+)*int cacheflush\s*\(.*?;' glibc
glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mips/sys/cachectl.h:extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/csky/sys/cachectl.h:extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes,
                       const int __op) __THROW;
glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nios2/sys/cachectl.h:extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
```

And with PCRE, you get access to most of perl's advanced regexp operators. Here, we use:

- `\w`, and `\s` for word and whitespace characters.
- `(?s)`: enables the `s` flag for `.` to also match on newline characters.
- `*?`: the non-greedy version of `*`. So it matches up to the *first* occurrence of `;` and not the last like the greedy version would.

See the `pcrepattern(3)` man page for details.

Comment: I like this version especially because pcregrep, as grep, tells you the file and line where it found the pattern :).  And also because the natural tool to search for a pattern is `*grep`

Comment: How do `(?s)` and the last `?` work?  I didn't find it.

Comment: @alx, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to invoke `sed` twice, you just check before entering the range, whether the begin/end happen to be on the same line.

```
$ find glibc/ -name '*.h' \
|xargs sed \
    -e "/${pattern}.*;\$/b"  \
    -e "/${pattern}/,/;\$/p" \
    -e 'd' ;
```

Note that it will be good if you constrain the `find` utility to locate regular files only, otherwise you might see warnings when `sed` operates upon a directory whose name ends in a `.h`

Comment: A minor bugfix: `"/${pattern}/,/;\$/!d"` --> `"/${pattern}/,/;\$/"'!d'` .  For some reason I can't make `!d` work with `"`.

Comment: That's coz the bang ! does not gel well under double quotes in bash. Your approach will work. I will provide sn alternative in the above. In bash 4.4 and above this issue is not seen.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. However, I'm on Debian 11 with bash 5.1 and the original code didn't work.

Comment: On that I am not sure as at my end gnu hash 4.4.23 on redhat linux it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a (ugly) solution:

1. Read from `/begin/` to `/^$/` (blank line), repeating the first line of the pattern, so that [`sed(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) can act on it on a subsequent step.
2. Use [`sed(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) to find from `/begin/` to `/end/`.  Keep blank lines at this step to be able to use [`uniq(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) to correctly remove on the next step the lines we repeated on step 1.
3. Use [`uniq(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) to remove the repeated lines.

```
$ syscall=cacheflush;
$ return=int;
$ pattern="^[a-z ]*${return} ${syscall}[ ]*(";
$ find glibc/ -name '*.h' \
  |xargs sed -n -e "/${pattern}/p" -e "/${pattern}/,/^$/p" \
  |sed -n -e "/${pattern}/,/;/p" -e '/^$/p' \
  |uniq;
extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, int __nbytes, int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes,
               const int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;

extern int cacheflush (void *__addr, const int __nbytes, const int __op) __THROW;
```

Please, come with a simpler solution :)